# How to describe the movement of a dress when the person twirls around?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

My friend put on a gown and then started twirling and moving around. The dress started to swirl around...

I want to eloquently explain this. Can someone please help me with this?

"My friend started twirling around and her dress was spiraling around"?

Comment: What's wrong with *swirl*? Or possibly *swish*?

Comment: The spin itself could be a *pirouette*, in which case you can reserve "twirl" for the movement of the dress. That said, why not try describing it with a simile or metaphor?

Comment: _Twirl_ and _swirl_ make a nice pair. _Twirl_ has a solid subject, but _swirl_ is for liquids and granular materials, like the folds of a skirt. Note that anyone in any clothes can twirl, but only a full skirt will swirl. Their phonosemantics is interesting, too: [`TW-`](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tw.pdf) versus [`SW`](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sw.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Flare*? "To open or spread outwards, as the sides of a bowl, a skirt, the mouth of a horn."

(As used in a lovely analogy from [a paper on the sun's magnetic field](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2003GeoRL..30vSSC2M&db_key=AST&data_type=HTML&format=&high=42ca922c9c03266): "Accordingly, the Sun with the heliosheet is like a bashful ballerina who is repeatedly trying to push her excessively high flaring skirt downward.").

Comment: "Giving herself a spinning twirl around, the full skirt of her dress flared out in a magnificent fluttering blur of brilliant red color." https://books.google.com/books?id=CE8b1Np3WMUC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22her+dress+flared+out%22&source=bl&ots=hTsuhf45il&sig=Uu9EgbcDafIajnjkMBBC_zNimao&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9HEtVc31JsHooATKwIGYDg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22her%20dress%20flared%20out%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

As she spun and twirled, her dress *billowed* and *rippled* accordingly

> **[billow](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/billow)** (Oxford Dictionaries)
>   (of fabric) fill with air and swell outwards
>
> - *her dress billowed out around her*